# Inset a new section in UICollectionView with new type of Cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on a chat app. I am using UICollectionView to display text and different type of text. I have 3 type of cells. In the first section, I am loading the first type of cell. in second, second type and in third, third type of cell loading. I have a button text field. When i click send button in text field i want to create new section of type first cell. I don't know how to create. Please help :)

Here is my Code:

```
//  ChatLogController.swift
//  Blubyn
//
//  Created by JOGENDRA on 02/02/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Jogendra Singh. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

fileprivate enum DefaultConstants {

    static let sendButtonImageName: String = "send-icon"
    static let voiceButtonImageName: String = "microphone"
}

enum Cells {
    case chatCell
    case oneWayFlight
    case twoWayFlight
}


class ChatLogController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    fileprivate var sideBar = SideBar()

    lazy var inputTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Send a message..."
        textField.delegate = self
        return textField
    }()

    let textView: UIView = {
        let textFieldview = UIView()
        textFieldview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textFieldview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textFieldview
    }()

    let cellId = "cellId"
    let oneWayCellId = "oneWayFlightCell"
    let twoWayCellId = "twoWayFlightCell"

    var numberOfSections: Int = 0
    var numberOfItemsInASection: Int = 0

    var cellType: Cells?

    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    var textViewBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var userMessages: [String] = ["Hey there!", "I want to book flight for Pokhara, Nepal", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s", "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.", "Book a hotel for me near lakeside", "book returning flight"]

    var systemMessages: [String] = ["Hello Jogendra!", "Pluto at your service - your guide and concierge to help you with the planning ticket booking and finding new and exotic places.", "Go on! Try me out. Won't take long. I promise."]

    lazy var messages: [String] = systemMessages + userMessages

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupInputComponents()
        sideBarSetup()

        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.0, left: 0, bottom: 52.0, right: 0)
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.chatbackgroundColor

        // Register Chat Cell
        collectionView?.register(ChatMessagesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        // Regsiter One Way Flight Cell
        let oneWayFlightCellNib = UINib(nibName: "OneWayFlightViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.register(oneWayFlightCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: oneWayCellId)

        // Register Two Way Flight Cell
        let twoWayFlightCellNib = UINib(nibName: "TwoWayFlightViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.register(twoWayFlightCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: twoWayCellId)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        // Register Notification, To know When Key Board Appear.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

        // Register Notification, To know When Key Board Hides.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)

        // De register the notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    fileprivate func setupInputComponents() {

        // Text View setups
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        textViewBottomAnchor = textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        textViewBottomAnchor?.isActive = true

        let voiceButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        let voiceButtonImage = UIImage(named: DefaultConstants.voiceButtonImageName)
        voiceButton.setImage(voiceButtonImage, for: .normal)
        textView.addSubview(voiceButton)
        voiceButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        voiceButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        voiceButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        voiceButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        voiceButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

        let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        let sendButtonImage = UIImage(named: DefaultConstants.sendButtonImageName)
        sendButton.setImage(sendButtonImage, for: .normal)
        textView.addSubview(sendButton)
        sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapSend), for: .touchUpInside)
        sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sendButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: voiceButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

        textView.addSubview(inputTextField)
        inputTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        inputTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0).isActive = true
        inputTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -4.0).isActive = true
        inputTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        inputTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let separator = UIView()
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        textView.addSubview(separator)
        separator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        separator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        separator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        separator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        separator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0).isActive = true

    }

    // MARK: - Keyboard Events

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        }
        let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double

        textViewBottomAnchor?.constant = -keyboardHeight
        UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration!, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {

        let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double
        textViewBottomAnchor?.constant = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration!, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }

    // MARK: - Collection View Methods

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return messages.count
        case 1:
            numberOfItemsInASection = 5
            return numberOfItemsInASection
        case 2:
            return 5
        default:
            numberOfItemsInASection = 5
            return numberOfItemsInASection
        }

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessagesCell

        let message = messages[indexPath.item]
        cell.chatTextView.text = message

        // Align chat cell according
        if userMessages.contains(message) {

            cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell.chatTextView.textColor = UIColor.black

            cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = true
            cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = false

        } else {

            cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.chatThemeColor
            cell.chatTextView.textColor = UIColor.white

            cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = false
            cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        }

        //Modify the width accordingly
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateFrameForText(text: message).width + 32.0

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cellType = Cells.chatCell
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let oneWayFlightCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: oneWayCellId, for: indexPath) as! OneWayFlightViewCell
            cellType = Cells.oneWayFlight
            return oneWayFlightCell
        } else {
            let twoWayFlightCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: twoWayCellId, for: indexPath) as! TwoWayFlightViewCell
            cellType = Cells.twoWayFlight
            return twoWayFlightCell
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        numberOfSections = 3
        return numberOfSections
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var cellHeight: CGFloat = 80.0
        let text = messages[indexPath.item]
        cellHeight = estimateFrameForText(text: text).height + 20.0

        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cellHeight = 112
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            cellHeight = 201
        }

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        //{top, left, bottom, right}
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)
    }

    private func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
        let size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)], context: nil)
    }

    @objc fileprivate func didTapSend() {

        if let enteredText = inputTextField.text, !enteredText.isEmpty {
            messages.append(enteredText)
            userMessages.append(enteredText)
        }
        collectionView?.reloadData()
        inputTextField.text = nil
    }

    fileprivate func sideBarSetup() {

        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Chat", "Hot Deals", "My Trips", "Experiences", "Settings", "Profile"])
        sideBar.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func didTapMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        sideBar.showSideBar(!sideBar.isSideBarOpen)
    }


    @IBAction func didTapHelp(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}

extension ChatLogController: SideBarDelegate {

    func SideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(_ index: Int) {

        switch index {
        case 0:
            sideBar.showSideBar(!sideBar.isSideBarOpen)
        case 1:
            sideBar.showSideBar(!sideBar.isSideBarOpen)
        case 2:
            sideBar.showSideBar(!sideBar.isSideBarOpen)
        case 3:
            sideBar.showSideBar(!sideBar.isSideBarOpen)
        case 4:
            let settingStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let settingsViewController = settingStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settingvc")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsViewController, animated: true)
        case 5:
            let profileStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let profileViewController = profileStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profilevc")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        inputTextField.endEditing(true)
    }

}

extension ChatLogController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        inputTextField.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
}
```

**Designs:**
See Screens Section of [this link][1].

**Achieved Designs:**

```
[![screenshot1][2]][2]
[![screenshot2][3]][3]
[![screenshot3][4]][4]
[![screenshot4][5]][5]

  [1]: https://blubyn.com/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ZLX.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLvAu.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBKbH.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sota4.png
```

Comment: just increase count of `numberOfSections` and reloadData for Collection view and handle that extra section index in `cellForItemAt` and `numberOfItemsInSection` accordingly.

Comment: Post screen design how u need?

Comment: @NeelBhasin I am able to insert new section but how to decide which cell should be present?

Comment: @McDonal_11 I added the Link for Designs. See the screenshot section.

Comment: 1. Normal Chat Msg, 2. Booking Area, 3. Scrolling Views. Am I right ?

Comment: 1. Normal Chat msg 2. OneSide flight booking cell 3. two way flight booking cell 3. Hotel booking cell. When i type new message I want to display a cell accordingly I get output from server.

Comment: Do u use storyboard ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 Yeah I am using storyboard but I am importing Cells from xib files. Message cell I design in code. All the cells have different cell classes. And I have sucessfully developed and impoted cell. I just want to present them accordingly.

Comment: I couldn't understood wr u r stuck ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 I am explaining again: I have 4 cells as i mentioned above. When I send new message from Input text field I am getting response from server. According to response from server, I want to present cell according.

Comment: That I understood well..!! Wr u r stuck? You don't know how to create? or how to show according to response ? like that am asking

Comment: how to show according to response ? @McDonal_11 I posted link of design which i implemented. Please see the screenshot links

Comment: Filter text fro Server Containing, "Book flight | Book hotel | two way | one way" ,, like that,

Comment: I dontknow y u r trying with CollectionView. TableView is best for this.

Comment: @McDonal_11 Do you know how to achieve this in TabelView?

Comment: How do I explain in Comments ? Create a TableView -> Create three diff Views, according to server msg, we have to show respective view.

Comment: Simple only. Not, that much toughest.

Comment: @McDonal_11 Can you please explain more?

Comment: try to create `sectionArray` and pre-define type of section you need and associate cell with that section this might solve your problem.